# Instead of displaying the user data of all users, how can the data of only the people who liked the logged in user be displayed?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Database

```
"people" : {
"9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2" : {
  "Coordinates" : {
    "latitude" : 15.78583,
    "longitude" : -4.406417
  },
  "Education" : "CS",
  "PhotoPosts" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/daylike-2f938.appspot.com/o/images%2FPhotoPosts?alt=media&token=65961f53-47f0-40f5-b990-02fc05ef94ad",
  "WhatIamConsideringBuying" : "Food",
  "caption" : 1563880684210,
  "likes" : 31,
  "peopleWhoLike" : {
    "-LkAU_XjMft_plwga-uw" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkAVL6rqnlATHsnMXix" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkAemFWYz4A1DkmTYrC" : "q3up6CyAe5PoEAooJwCclOGGcZd2",
    "-LkAfAIvWE9lB-Os0IYK" : "K1eqsVZfKGgIf0sS1UZcPNxY62x1",
    "-LkAgZNIsTlnuJzyOKO7" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkB5k0o89n2dFS6bUzH" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkB5k3USKvBZR62H6t8" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkBHsFvOxtc5M_eLisY" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkBQObubRDb1eY-L5ME" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkBRuvEb0KX20Blrhpq" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkBSSKYKEmtsT68w564" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkGPtRpz_AwBhA_4Mhx" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkGZA9t85w21219wPcZ" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkG_SwHgKvQ-4hIGzVC" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkG_ZLibLrGs2G62Pfr" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkG_sDlzzMp3phVceTW" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkGaKINLcD0j9_NtYa_" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkGd0JcyfHwQXPUPK0U" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkGdYuC1sGCUXpizo56" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkGdeN3mG3vpWVx3Jci" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkGdfjNR0dPPztJhUtr" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkGdfyOF3Rg7fgh1Noo" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkGdgJX7R-w8IB2ns50" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkP99lTiKk5tXamW5yW" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkP9YuvzkKIOmotFNSx" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkQw0h80_jSCYZs8mNu" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2",
    "-LkT_bvTo8SlYTtJR12Q" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkThUcjHQWLUvQk4xKQ" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-LkYMJ4f6Cwy-OD0Ca-W" : "q3up6CyAe5PoEAooJwCclOGGcZd2",
    "-Lk_1YzFt-h0UPSNpp82" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1",
    "-Lk_1_yh6dVzyCMv9ghS" : "KRFfYoO8IwO1qiHknzP9wLCmUSp1"
  },
  "postID" : "9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2",
  "users" : "nane19@aol.com"
},
```

The above is the database. Basically all the user's who liked this person will have their data(photo etc) displayed. The people who liked are found as a child in whoever they liked.

I added this line in the below code that just displayed all the user data (photo etc) for all users: "for thisUsersUid in thisUsersUid1"

```
 let thisUsersUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid //Mr. Dunn's uid
    let thisUsersUid1 = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(thisUsersUid!).child("peopleWhoLikedMe")

    ref = Database.database().reference().child("people");

    ref.observe(DataEventType.value,  with: {snapshot in

        if snapshot.childrenCount>0{

            self.people.removeAll()

            /////This line describes what I want to do, but  I don't know how to write it in formal code : for thisUsersUid in thisUsersUid1 ////// {
            for people in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                if people.key != thisUsersUid { //do not add this users info to the array
                let peopleObject = people.value as? [String: AnyObject]

                let peopleEducation = peopleObject?["Education"] as? String
                    let peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying = peopleObject?["WhatIamConsideringBuying"] as? String
                    let peoplePhotoPosts = peopleObject?["PhotoPosts"]  as? String
                    let peopleimageDownloadURL = peopleObject?["imageDownloadURL"] as? String
                    let peoplepostID = peopleObject?["postID"] as? String
                    let peoplepeopleWhoLike = peopleObject?["peopleWhoLike"] as? String

                    let peopl = Userx(Education: peopleEducation, WhatIamConsideringBuying: peopleWhatIamConsideringBuying, PhotoPosts: peoplePhotoPosts, imageDownloadURL: peopleimageDownloadURL, postID: peoplepostID, peopleWhoLike: peoplepeopleWhoLike)
                        self.people.append(peopl)
  }
                        self.table.reloadData()
```

Here is the code that made the database reference to peopleWhoLike

```
     ref.child("people").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with:  {(snapshot) in

        if let people = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let updateLikes: [String: Any] = ["peopleWhoLike/\(keyToPost)" : Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid]
            ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(updateLikes, withCompletionBlock: { (error, reff) in



                if error == nil {
                    ref.child("people").child(self.postID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snap) in
                        if let properties = snap.value as?[String: AnyObject]{
                            if let likes = properties["peopleWhoLike"] as? [String : AnyObject] {
                                let count = likes.count

                            let update = ["likes" : count]
                                ref.child("people").child(self.postID).updateChildValues(update)
```

At the end, in stead of all users' data being displayed, only the data from the people who liked the logged in user will be displayed.

///Here is my code based on answer by Jay

```
func printPersonInfo(uid: String) {
    let usersRef = Database.database().reference().child("people")
    let thisUser = usersRef.child(uid)
    thisUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let education = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Education").value as? String ?? "No Education"
        let whatIamConsideringBuying = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "WhatIamConsideringBuying").value as? String ?? "No WhatIamConsideringBuying"
        print(education, whatIamConsideringBuying)

    })
}

func loadPeopleWhoLikeMe() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let thisUserRef = Database.database().reference().child("people").child(uid)
    let myPeopleRef = thisUserRef.child("peopleWhoLike")
    myPeopleRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let peopleArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for person in peopleArray {
            let personUid = person.value as! String
            self.printPersonInfo(uid: personUid)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: what info the peopleWhoLike contains, people data or just the id of the people

Comment: Just the ID of the people

Comment: Can you elaborate on what specifically is stored? You say just the id but there is a key and a value stored `"-LkAU_XjMft_plwga-uw" : "NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2"`. What is the key, and what is the value?

Comment: but you wnat show in a tableview a list of id only?? or get those id to get the people name from the list of name.

Comment: @Jay good catch. I overlooked that. The NMNQYJ5z64fATK2MMs7m0ggHl0k2 is the ID of the person who liked (As in he has a child immediately below people as well). The LkAU_XjMft_plwga-uw looks to only be a random number given to that like. I certainly have not used LkAU_XjMft_plwga-uw anywhere else. Just for reference, I'll add the code that created that part of the database to the question.

Comment: @kjoe So, to summarize what the middle code currently does: It gets the pics + that datapoint for ALL USERS via the snapshot for displaying on a page.
What needs to happen: What is happening for all users needs to only happen for the users who liked the logged in profile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have two firebase nodes, one to store 'people' and one to store the actual users, here's some code to do what you want.

```
people
   uid_0
      likes: 45
      peopleWhoLike:
         random_0: uid_1
   uid_1
       like: 12
       peopleWhoLike:
          random_0: uid_2
          random_1: uid_3
```

and then a main users node that stores all the user info

```
users
   uid_0
      email: "bill@mostexcellent.com"
      name: "bill"
   uid_1
      email: "ziggy@stardust.com"
      name: "ziggy"
   uid_2
      email: "leroy@jenkins.com"
      name: "leroy"
   uid_3
      email: "ted@ mostexcellent.com"
      name: "ted"
```

The objective is the to read the current users 'people' node and get information of the people who like this user. Assume the logged in user is uid_1 and we will be retrieving uid_2 and uid_3's info.

```
func loadPeopleWhoLikeMe() {
    let thisUserRef = self.ref.child("people").child("uid_1")
    let myPeopleRef = thisUserRef.child("peopleWhoLike")
    myPeopleRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let peopleArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
        for person in peopleArray {
            let personUid = person.value as! String
            self.printPersonInfo(withUid: personUid)
        }
    })
}
```

The above code gets a reference to uid_1's peopleWhoLike child node, loads in all of the children and then iterates over each one to get the corresponding uid of each person who likes them. As each is being read, we pass that users uid to another function to read, in this case, the email and name, and print that to console. It could load their picture or other tasks as well.

```
func printPersonInfo(withUid: String) {
    let usersRef = self.ref.child("users")
    let thisUser = usersRef.child(withUid)
    thisUser.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No name"
        let email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as? String ?? "No email"
        print(name, email)
    })
}
```

and when this code is run against the above structure, the output is

```
leroy leroy@jenkins.com
ted ted@mostexcellent.com
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I'll try to implement and get back. I only have 1 node, but the structure is exactly like you put it there, only with "users" being the "people" of the top node. In this example, email, name, like, peopleWhoLike are all underneath each other.

Comment: @Jat do you know why I may be getting an error: Value of type 'peopleWhoLikedMe' has no member 'ref'; did you mean 'self'? for the first line. I added these two lines before it:         let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference(). I also turned "uid_1" into uid as I don't have a child "uid_1". Is that correct?

Comment: @noname87f self.ref is a class var that points to the root ref of *my* Firebase. You would substitute your firebase for that. uid_0, uid_1 are my users uid's - you can see them in my *users* node. They generally look like -Jyia9osjk90j49df. If you read through my answer, I am looking up this users followers, and this user has a uid of uid_1, as shown in the code. Getting the current users uid with `let uid = Auth.auth...` like you are doing it is correct.

Comment: Thanks. I think I got that part down then. My question now becomes: for the last part does there need to be a users node or can I get it from the people node as well? I am not finding anything in the code that is wrong, so I wonder why it is not printing. My last part is exactly like yours, except it is people i.s.o users and uid instead of withUid (but I tried it as withUid too). The previous part then also has it as self.printPersonInfo(uid: personUid)

Comment: If you don't have a /users node (having a /users node is common practice so you may want to consider that) you can can simply get the same information from the people node. A node is a node, you just need to account for the different key names. However, looking at your code you're trying to access nodes in the people/uid node that don't exist; e.g. *PhotoPosts* doesn't exist in the people node in your question.

Comment: Aah, I took PhotoPosts out to keep the question simple, but forgot to take it out of the snapshot. To keep this question accurate for future visitors, I have now put the database entry of one complete user in the question. I am currently trying to get the PhotoPosts, Education, and WhatIamConsideringBuying child of the users who liked.

Comment: @noname87f The code to do that is in my answer in the `func printPersonInfo(withUid: String)` function! You'll just need to to adopt it to the keys you are using... `let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "Education")...`

Comment: thanks. Yeah, I had made that part consistent with mine (education etc). I went through all lines again and again. Everything seems consistent with your answer. I will put my code mirroring yours in the question . Do you see some mistake that I'm missing?

Comment: @noname87f I copied and pasted your code and duplicated your structure and it works for me - it prints education and what the user is considering buying for each user in the *peopleWhoLikeMe* node. The problem is that the child keys of the people node are not uid's... i.e. `9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2` will not be a uid but `-jnZ_WsGgRvQ-4mdGzVC` would be

Comment: i.e. in the *people* node, the child keys need to be a uid so */people/some_uid_0* and then */people/some_uid_1*

Comment: Thanks for doing that. Where do you get jnZ_WsGgRvQ-4mdGzVC? Did that come from the output? I don't quite understand the last sentence.   Edit: Just saw the second comment.

Comment: Re 2nd comment, I am pretty sure they are uids. For example the 9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2 appears in peopleWhoLike of another user.

Comment: Don't read too much into that. My point was the child nodes keys under the */people* node need to be uid's and if the current users uid isn't a child key, it won't work. Your code works for me so you need to add some print statements and step through the code to determine where it's failing. On what line or which var isn't being populated with what you expect. Try adding a `print(withUid)` statement and see if `9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2` is printed.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem. print(uid) does not print 9RYUttVhCzXKs6H1XnZ63TZ8Dun2. I tried it on another page that uses the uid and there it works, so the error is not with the uid but with how it interacts on this page.

Comment: Ok, so that goes beyond the scope of this question. I would compare whatever printed to the Authentication section in the Firebase Console to ensure you are logged in as the correct user. Then check your Firebase to see if you have a node of */people/whatever printed*. Your code works with the structure we've discussed so the issue lies elsewhere. If my answer helped, please accept it so it can help others. Do some troubleshooting and post another question on that topic if needed and we'll take a look. .

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have accepted it because it works after you tried it. It is very weird. I just put let uid = ... and print (uid) just outside the function, above it, and it prints. So for whatever reason uid doesn't like being in the function. I'll let you go on to help others, I guess my final question would then just be where in your file did you put these 2 functions? I can only think it might be that.

Comment: Update:I removed func loadPeopleWhoLikeMe() and just put the code of the function under super view did load and it worked! Thanks! From there I should be able to display it in in cells.